# Unable to get Google API key and GoogleSearch.Wsdl which are required to run a perl script

Tags: perl, wsdl, google-api, yahoo

Apologies if this is trivial.

I was trying to run this code - http://oreilly.com/pub/h/974#code to get URLs from Yahoo! directory.

I was unable to get the google API base key and found at net that it's not required any more.

I needed google.wsdl as well and found at Google's API FAQ (http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/api_faq.html#tech4) that it can be taken from http://api.google.com/GoogleSearch.wsdl which is throwing 404 error.

Is it also not required? If yes, then just changing the method call by reducing the number of parameters will work?

Does anyone have any idea regarding the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GoogleSearch.wsdl` file can be found [here](http://dic.googlecode.com/files/GoogleSearch.wsdl)

Comment: Yes, I got that file and changed method signature to avoid "Google API key", still its not giving any output.

Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 5):

the [Google Search SOAP API](https://developers.google.com/soap-search/) service is now retired; there are a few tutorials referencing it that are now in need of an update; so even though there's the wsdl file accessible, a SOAP request gives 404 from the wsdl file's url, api.google.com/search/beta2