# how can adding wsdl file to vs?

Tags: asp.net

I want to implement a simple meta search engine with asp.net that integrate result of 2 search engine without ranking the results of them.
I know first i should add wsdl file into vs so I downloaded wsdl file of google and it locate for example on my c: drive of my laptop but when in vs i want to add serviece refrence and i entered the path of my wsdl file vs can not fine it
I also try add web refrence,I don't know where is my problem 
I attach the picture of it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIcBs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43R6i.png)

Comment: where is your the WSDL file located on your computer?  Try `http://api.google.com/GoogleSearch.wsdl`

Comment: I also try http://api.google.com/GoogleSearch.wsdl but it doesn't work it has 404 error

Answer (score 0):

please try this instead :

```
http://dic.googlecode.com/files/GoogleSearch.wsdl
```

[image]

ref : [Unable to get Google API key and GoogleSearch.Wsdl which are required to run a perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177415/unable-to-get-google-api-key-and-googlesearch-wsdl-which-are-required-to-run-a-p)

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work It has error : An error ecured while attempting to fine services at http://dic.googlecode.com/files/GoogleSearch.wsdl

Comment: that's error when you click "GO" ? else, Can you show me `Web.config` file, i need to see your endpoint tag.

Comment: here is my web config :<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: can you see this code in your Web.config ?   `<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GoogleSearchBinding" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://api.google.com/search/beta2" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="GoogleSearchBinding" contract="GoogleSvcRef.GoogleSearchPort"
        name="GoogleSearchPort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>`

Comment: no my web config doesn't contain these...for implementing a meta search engine first i create a website project in visual studio but i don't know it is true or not ,should i open another type of project for working with web service? if yes what is that?

Comment: what version of your VS?

Comment: I think your vs version is support. Now, you can new project and choose Web -> ASP.NET Web Application -> choose your templates ( MVC or Web Forms or API or ... ) and add Web Service Refference ( it's work fine for me ).

Comment: for add web service refrence in url what url should i enter? i have wsdl file on my computer i downloded it before also i tried the first link that you recomended but it has error

Comment: Let me see your error when you enter `http://dic.googlecode.com/files/GoogleSearch.wsdl` for add web service reference.

Comment: There was an error downloading 'http://dic.googlecode.com/files/GoogleSearch.wsdl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

Comment: can you download new wsdl file by enter url `http://dic.googlecode.com/files/GoogleSearch.wsdl` on web browser ?